# how to pop the last three element of an array

Tags: perl

I have a certain array from which I want to remove the last three element (constant number, because I want a list of subdirectory which are in a directory where there is 3 files).

Is there a better and nicer solution than this one ?

```
my @list = (`ls --group-directories-first`);
pop @list;
pop @list;
pop @list;
```

Comment: Oops. Just came up with that :
`op @liste for(0..2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) is also the solution I'd advise.

However, since you're working with the end of an array and just wanting to destroy those trailing elements instead of saving them to another structure, you could also just edit the last array index:

```
$#list -= 3;
```

The above is reduces the size of the `@list` array by 3 elements.  Here's another example:

```
my @a = (1..10);

$#a -= 4;

print "@a\n";
# Prints: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

```
splice @list, -3;
```

Where `-3` denotes an offset of 3 from the end. This will remove elements from that offset and onward.

It's worth noting that parsing output from `ls` is a horrible idea. You can do the exact same thing with Perl code:

```
my @list = grep -d, glob "*";
```

The `-d` is a file check, which checks if the current argument is a directory.

Comment: @kinezana no. `splice` modifies the array in-place. `substr` returns a new string.

Comment: @rightfold `substr` can also modify the string if it is used as an lvalue: `substr($foo, -3) = "txt"`.

Comment: @kinezana I suppose so, yes, you can use it for a great many things, though.

Comment: @kinezana If this answers your question, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark.